# change CSS root permanently on whole website

Tags: javascript, css, root, blazor

I'm creating a website using Blazor and trying to create a Settings page where I can change the appearance:

[My Settings Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNjF4.png)

[My root file]

```
:root {
    --BodyColorDarkMode: #ddd;
    --HeaderColorDarkMode: #999;
    --TextColorDarkMode: #000;
}
```

[My JavaScript code]

```
function SetBodyColor(color) {
    var items = ["--BodyColorDarkMode", "--HeaderColorDarkMode", "--TextColorDarkMode"];
    for (i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
        if (color[i] != "")
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty(items[i], color[i]);
    }
}
```

[What's happening in the inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8iA9.png)

Currently it's working but only on the settings page. Please help me to make this change permanent to my whole project.

Comment: You would have to do something on the server side to change what is sent to the browser. In other words, save the values to a database, file, or some other persistence mechanism. Or, if the change is to work for each browser, save it to localStorage or some other client-based persistence mechanism. There are many, many questions about doing either of those options on Stack Overflow already, as well as many tutorials around the web.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response,  I will try to make a database for storing this data.